# ValueError and TypeError in python

Tags: python, typeerror, valueerror

I can't completely understand the difference between Type and Value error in Python3x.

Why do we get a ValueError when I try float('string') instead of TypeError? shouldn't this give also a TypeError because I am passing a variable of type 'str' to be converted into float?

```
In [169]: float('string')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-169-f894e176bff2> in <module>()
----> 1 float('string')

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'string'
```

Comment: Some strings can be converted to float, for example `123`.

Comment: And it's the **value** of the string (`'string'`) that's problematic because it is not convertible to a float.

Comment: Another valid example is `float("infinity")`.

Comment: Another one is `float("nan")`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

A Value error is

> Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value

the `float` function can take a string, ie `float('5')`, it's just that the value `'string'` in `float('string')` is an inappropriate (non-convertible) string

On the other hand,

> Passing arguments of the wrong type (e.g. passing a list when an int is expected) should result in a TypeError

so you would get a `TypeError` if you tried `float(['5'])` because a list can never be converted into a float.

[Cite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html)

Comment: I was confused when float('string') was raising ValueError instead of TypeError. I totally ignored the fact that float('5') is a valid piece of code in python. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

ValueError a function is called on a value of the correct type, but with an inappropriate value

TypeError : a function is called on  a value of an inappropriate type

Answer (score 3):

They are well explained in
[Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html).

I would add examples for both of them:

TypeError:

```
10 + 'a'
```

ValueError:

```
int("hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just would like to add one more point to David's answer.

**TypeError can also occur, when we pass incorrect no of arguments to a function.**

eg:

```
def hello(int x,int y):
    pass

hello(12)
```

This also gives you TypeError:

**hello() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'**

Comment: this does not really look like python code.

Answer (score 0):

**ValueError and TypeError have very subtle differences**

```
float('Dog') # Gives you an ValueError
```

The above statement gives you a ValueError, it may sound a little confusing, but now you realize that it makes sense.

The float function can accept a **number** or a **string** whose content is numeric as an argument.
Pay attention that I said that it accepts the string if it is a number, otherwise if the argument has a **string of characters** like dog, the type of argument that the float function receives is correct because it still received a string but the value it received is an **inappropriate** value for the float function.

According to the above, if an operation or function is given an argument whose type is correct, but the **value** inside that argument is **inappropriate**, TypeError will occur.The following example shows that an argument whose type is wrong causes a TypeError

```
var_ = [1, 2, 3] # Create a iterable 
float(var_)
```

Note that the float function can take a string or a number, but the value inside the variable is an **iterable**, which does not match the type that the float function takes, so a TypeError is received due to the inappropriate type.

[Python documentation about the float function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float)

[Python documentation about TypeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError)

[Python documentation about ValueError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html?highlight=valueerror#ValueError)