# How to calculate the age from date of birth when there are NaN in between some of the rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I want to calculate the age from date of birth in my pandas dataframe. However, some of the date in  the column are `NaN` which cause me some error due to the format is different. This is my code:

```
dob = {'DOB': ['11/29/1986', 'NaN', '02/23/2006']}
  
# Creating dataframe
df33 = pd.DataFrame(data = dob)

# This function converts given date to age
def age(born):
    born = datetime.strptime(born, "%m/%d/%Y").date()
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, 
                                      today.day) < (born.month, 
                                                    born.day))
  
df33['Age'] = df33['DOB'].apply(age)

display(df33)
```

May I know how should I modified the code so that it can ignore the `NaN` values and continue to compute the age for the other rows? Those rows with `NaN` can just leave it as `NaN`. Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `NaN` a string or `np.nan` type?

Comment: The `NaN` are caused by the missing values in the data source, so when I import the data from data source, it shows `NaN` for the empty value in python

Comment: Okay. Answered!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your age function to leave rows unchanged by adding exception handling to the `age` function.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date

# added pd.NaT to posted data
dob = {'DOB': ['11/29/1986', 'NaN', pd.NaT, '02/23/2006']}

# Creating dataframe
df33 = pd.DataFrame(data = dob)

def age(born):
    try:
        born = datetime.strptime(born, "%m/%d/%Y").date()
        today = date.today()
        return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, 
                                          today.day) < (born.month, 
                                                        born.day))
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return born    # leave unchanged

dob = {'DOB': ['11/29/1986', 'NaN', '02/23/2006']}
df33['Age'] = df33['DOB'].apply(age)

display(df33)
```

*Output*

```
    DOB Age
0   11/29/1986  35
1   NaN        NaN
2   NaT        NaT
3   02/23/2006  16
```

Comment: Thanks DarryIG, the NaN are caused by the missing values in the data source, so when I import the data from data source, it shows NaN for the empty value in python. When I use your code, I get this error: `strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float`

Comment: @weizer -- are you saying it works on your posted data case but not on your real data?

Comment: @weizer -- added ignore for TypeError (i.e. will ignore strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float).

Comment: ya, you are right, because the posted data is simulated data, which means the NaN is actually a text instead of pd.NaT, my actual data should be pd.NaT since the NaN is caused by missing value.

Comment: It works perfectly now, thanks! What is the different between `ValueError` and `TypeError`?

Comment: @weizer -- added pd.NaT to your posted data.  As you see the  try-except still works.   ValueError handles NaN and TypeError handles pd.NaT.

Comment: @weizer Check out [ValueError and TypeError in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343387/valueerror-and-typeerror-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `relativedelta` without using a separate function.

**Install the modules**

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import numpy as np

dob = {'DOB': ['11/29/1986', np.nan, '02/23/2006']}

# Creating dataframe
df33 = pd.DataFrame(data=dob)

df33["DOB"] = pd.to_datetime(df33["DOB"])
df33["Age"] = df33.apply(lambda x: relativedelta(datetime.now().date(), x['DOB']).years if x.notnull().all() else pd.NaT, axis=1)
print(df33)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
         DOB   Age
0 1986-11-29  35.0
1        NaT   NaT
2 2006-02-23  16.0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This below answer is only for you to fix your issue. I recommend using a library like [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) to correctly compute the age.

The 'NaN' is not really numpy.nan, you should modify the `dob` dictionary as:

```
dob = {'DOB': ['11/29/1986', pd.NaT, '02/23/2006']}
```

for datetime types its better to use pandas NaT value to indicate not a time value.

Then you could use it to convert to pd.datetime and then do other stuff.

---

But a quick fix *without modifying your dictionary `dob`* is :

include this check at the beginning:

```
if born == 'NaN':
    return 'NaN'
```

Comment: When i include the checking, then this error appeared, any idea?  `strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float`

Comment: Did you modify the dictionary by changing to 'NaN' to pd.NaT? Don't do that. That is only when you work with datetime types, it seems your dictionary has str types. So don't modify dictionary and just include that check in your method.

Comment: the example that I show above in the question is a simulated data, for my actual data, it seems like the `NaN` is pd.NaT, and hence it give me that error. But your solution work well with the simulated data, how should I modify the pd.NaT?

Comment: The NaN are caused by the missing values in the data source, so when I import the data from data source, it shows NaN for the empty value in python.